# cocos2d-x convert UIImage to CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimage, ccsprite, cocos2d-x

has anyone an idea how to convert a UIImage to cocos2d-x CCSprite.
My latest attempt was was:
1. Store the UIImage as png on the phone
2. Load the png as a CCSprite

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:true];
CCSprite *sprite = CCSprite::spriteWithFile(imagePath);
```

But this crashed in CCObject retain function

```
void CCObject::retain(void)
{
    CCAssert(m_uReference > 0, "reference count should greater than 0");

    ++m_uReference;
}
```

And I do not understand how Walzer Wangs suggestion works
http://cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/3922

```
CCImage::initWithImageData(void* pData, int nDataLen, ...)
CCTexture2D::initWithImage(CCImage* uiImage);
CCSprite::initWithTexture(CCTexture2D* pTexture);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my own Problem. You can't create a CCSprite before the CCDirector is initialized. There are missing some config settings and cocos releases the image right after it is instantiated.

Answer (score 2):

```
CCSprite* getCCSpriteFromUIImage(UIImage *photo) {
    CCImage *imf =new CCImage();
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);
    NSUInteger len = [imgData length];
    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(byteData, [imgData bytes], len);
    imf->initWithImageData(byteData,imgData.length);
    imf->autorelease();
    CCTexture2D* pTexture = new CCTexture2D();
    pTexture->initWithImage(imf);
    pTexture->autorelease();
    CCSprite *sprit = new CCSprite();
    sprit->createWithTexture(pTexture);
    sprit->autorelease();
    DebugLog("size :%f :%f ",sprit->getContentSize().width , sprit->getContentSize().height);

    return sprit;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Answering is nice, but we'd like to encourage to you provide some context and explanation : this might help people with similar issues to understand how to solve them. Again, welcome !

Comment: A malloc, but no free? That ok?

Comment: @Jonny Cocos destroys stuff when its' released, I'm pretty sure it frees it too.

Answer (score 0):

Save uiimage to documents directory first

now get it using getWritablePath

```
Texture2D* newTexture2D = new Texture2D();
Image* JpgImage     = new Image();

JpgImage->initWithImageFile("your image path.jpg");
newTexture2D->initWithData(JpgImage->getData(),JpgImage->getDataLen(),Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGB888,JpgImage->getWidth(),JpgImage->getHeight(),Size(JpgImage->getWidth(),JpgImage->getHeight()));
```