# Load/init Button with in memory imagery like Texture2D

Tags: cocos2d-x

I can only find methods to create `Button`:s from disk-based image files.
How would I set/change a button's normal/highlighted states from in-memory data like Texture2D, Image etc?

Cocos2D-x v3.5

Answer (score 0):

**Update 20160408:**
I Googled this again, and Google suggested this page... and I have to thank my past self :-)
This time I wrote a handy tool function:

```
void Mjcocoshelper::rendernodetospriteframecache(Node* node, std::string nameincache) {
    const Size SIZE = node->getBoundingBox().size;
    auto render = RenderTexture::create(SIZE.width, SIZE.height);
    render->begin();

    const Vec2 POS_BEFORE = node->getPosition();
    const bool IGNORE_BEFORE = node->isIgnoreAnchorPointForPosition();
    const float SCALEY_BEFORE = node->getScaleY();

    node->ignoreAnchorPointForPosition(false);
    node->setPosition(SIZE.width * 0.5f, SIZE.height * 0.5f);
    node->setScaleY(-1.0f); // Or it gets upside down?
    node->visit();
    node->ignoreAnchorPointForPosition(IGNORE_BEFORE);
    node->setPosition(POS_BEFORE);
    node->setScaleY(SCALEY_BEFORE);

    render->end();

    auto spriteNew = render->getSprite();
    Texture2D* texture2d = spriteNew->getTexture();
    SpriteFrame* spriteframeOff = SpriteFrame::createWithTexture(texture2d, Rect(0, 0, texture2d->getContentSize().width, texture2d->getContentSize().height));
    SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFrame(spriteframeOff, nameincache);
}
```

Old:

I figured out this kinda neat workaround:

```
std::string framenameOff;
{
    Texture2D* texture2d = mjpromobuttonx.textureOff();
    SpriteFrame* spriteframeOff = SpriteFrame::createWithTexture(texture2d, Rect(0, 0, texture2d->getContentSize().width, texture2d->getContentSize().height));
    framenameOff = "autobutton_off_" + std::to_string(++buttonsaddedtocacheoff);
    SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFrame(spriteframeOff, framenameOff);
}
std::string framenameOn;
{
    Texture2D* texture2d = mjpromobuttonx.textureOff();
    SpriteFrame* spriteframeOn = SpriteFrame::createWithTexture(texture2d, Rect(0, 0, texture2d->getContentSize().width, texture2d->getContentSize().height));
    framenameOn = "autobutton_on_" + std::to_string(++buttonsaddedtocacheon);
    SpriteFrameCache::getInstance()->addSpriteFrame(spriteframeOn, framenameOn);
}

Button* item = Button::create(framenameOff, framenameOn, framenameOff, TextureResType::PLIST);
```

So what it does, it adds spriteframes on the fly to the sprite frame cache. We have to make sure that the names we store them with don't overwrite anything else, and we also have to keep creating new names for each image we add to the cache. On some extreme sad occasion maybe this would overwrite some existing image, so I'll give this some more thouhght... maybe... sometime...

Bonus:
I did have a ObjC framework I created earlier that fetches images from a remote server... um for now I reused it, and also needed to convert the UIImage:s the framework ended up with to something I could pass to C++ and then Cocos2D-x... so I used this, it works pretty well:

```
Texture2D* getTexture2DFromUIImage(UIImage *photo) {
#warning TODO: Make use of this baby later? Does it work? Do we need to free after malloc?
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134000/129202
    Image *imf = new Image();
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo);
    NSUInteger len = [imgData length];
    Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
    memcpy(byteData, [imgData bytes], len);
    imf->initWithImageData(byteData,imgData.length);
    imf->autorelease();
    Texture2D* pTexture = new Texture2D();
    pTexture->initWithImage(imf);
    pTexture->autorelease();
    return pTexture;
}
```

Now I'm just guessing that the malloc in that function should really have a free somewhere after it... but that's [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134000/129202).